# open password protected docx file

Tags: macos, cocoa, password-protection

I want to open password protect Microsoft Word file in my MAC Application.

I have already tried "AESCrypt" for save & open Password Protected file but i need to open secure file that is manually created.

```
#import "AESCrypt.h"

- (IBAction) OpenFile: (id) sender{
    NSOpenPanel * zOpenPanel = [NSOpenPanel openPanel];
    [zOpenPanel setAllowedFileTypes:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[[fileType selectedCell] title]]];
    NSInteger zIntResult = [zOpenPanel runModal];

    if (zIntResult == NSAlertDefaultReturn) {
        NSURL *zUrl = [zOpenPanel URL];

        // read the file
        txtView.string=@"";

        NSString * zStr = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:zUrl
                                                   encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding
                                                      error:NULL];

        [self decryptFile:zStr];
    }

    //    NSLog(@"zStr=\n%@",zStr);
}

- (void) decryptFile : (NSString *) aStrFileContent {
    NSAlert *alert = [NSAlert alertWithMessageText:nil
                                     defaultButton:@"Set"
                                   alternateButton:@"Cancel"
                                       otherButton:nil
                         informativeTextWithFormat:@"Please enter a password to decrypt your file with:"];
    [alert setIcon:[NSImage imageNamed:nil]];
    NSSecureTextField *input = [[NSSecureTextField alloc] initWithFrame:NSMakeRect(0, 0, 300, 24)];
    [alert setAccessoryView:input];
    NSInteger button = [alert runModal];
    if (button == NSAlertDefaultReturn) {
        NSString *decyptData = [AESCrypt decrypt:aStrFileContent password:[input stringValue]];

        if ([decyptData length] == 0) {
             [self alertView:@"Error.." InformationText:@"Please Enter Correct Password to get File Data!!!"];


        }
        txtView.string = decyptData;
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Pooja are you able to read non-password docx file?

Comment: already read Non-Password docx file but need Password protected docx file

Comment: show the code how you reading a docx

Comment: please check above Anoop Vaidya